# Exclusive Full Join in r

Tags: r, join

Trying to implement exclusive full join in r code.

[image: Exclusive Full Join Image.]

Implemented the below code which works correctly but is the correct approach since the filter is filled lots of conditions. Since this is the sample code didn't add much columns but in real time scenario we have many columns so adding up the columns to filter would make things difficult.

**So any other better approach available ?**

```
library(tidyverse)

persons = data.frame(
  name = c("Ponting", "Clarke", "Dave", "Bevan"),
  age = c(24, 32, 26, 29),
  col1 = c(1,2,3,4),
  col2 = c("a", "z", "h", "p")
)

person_sports = data.frame(
  name = c("Ponting", "Dave", "Roshan"),
  sports = c("soccer", "tennis", "boxing"),
  rank = c(8, 4, 1),
  col3 = c("usa", "australia", "england"),
  col4 = c("a", "f1", "z2")
)

persons %>% full_join(person_sports, by = c("name")) %>%
  filter((is.na(age) & is.na(col1) & is.na(col2)) | (is.na(sports) & is.na(rank) & is.na(col3) & is.na(col4)))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `complete.cases`. This will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE where FALSE indicates an NA is found on a given row in at least one column.

```
persons %>% full_join(person_sports, by = c("name")) %>% .[!complete.cases(.), ]
#     name age col1 col2 sports rank    col3 col4
# 2 Clarke  32    2    z   <NA>   NA    <NA> <NA>
# 4  Bevan  29    4    p   <NA>   NA    <NA> <NA>
# 5 Roshan  NA   NA <NA> boxing    1 england   z2
```

As an alternative, which works similarly to the above, use `filter_all` and `any_vars` from the `dplyr` package.

```
persons %>% full_join(person_sports, by = c("name")) %>% filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))
#     name age col1 col2 sports rank    col3 col4
# 1 Clarke  32    2    z   <NA>   NA    <NA> <NA>
# 2  Bevan  29    4    p   <NA>   NA    <NA> <NA>
# 3 Roshan  NA   NA <NA> boxing    1 england   z2
```

Finally, since you mentioned your actual dataset is much bigger, you might want to compare to a `data.table` solution and see what works best in your real world data.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(persons)
setDT(person_sports)

merge(persons, person_sports, by = "name", all = TRUE) %>% .[!complete.cases(.)]
#      name age col1 col2 sports rank    col3 col4
# 1:  Bevan  29    4    p     NA   NA      NA   NA
# 2: Clarke  32    2    z     NA   NA      NA   NA
# 3: Roshan  NA   NA   NA boxing    1 england   z2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...  by the way what does `(.)` denote in `complete.cases(.)` and `is.na(.)`

Comment: The `.` is the dot placeholder from the `%>%` pipe operator. Anywhere there is a `.` on the right hand side, the left hand side of the operator will be placed. That way you can use the left hand side several times in the right hand side, or in a position other than the first function parameter of the right hand side. 

Check out `help("%>%", package = "magrittr")` for more explanation and examples.